# jquery hiding submenu when change from one submenu opition to another

Tags: javascript, jquery, submenu

I have a menu with a sub-menu of two options, as you leave one sub-menu item to go to the next the sub-menu disappears. How Do I stop this?

jQuery:

```
// SHOW TAKE ATTENDANCE SUB MENU
    $('#take_attendance').hover(function(){
        $('#taskbar_sub ul').fadeIn(100);
    });
    $('#taskbar_sub').mouseout(function(){
        $('#taskbar_sub ul').hide();
    });
// /SHOW TAKE ATTENDANCE SUB MENU
```

Comment: Show your (relevant) HTML, CSS and, if possible, use [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net), or similar, to post a live demo that reproduces your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It'll be hard to debug without seeing the HTML/CSS.

It sounds like one of three things:

- Your submenu is not nested within #take_attendance.
- Your submenu ul is positioned outside the parent element (floated or absolutely positioned)
- Your submenu li has margins below each item.

To get a better answer, I would suggest using jsfiddle to input sample HTML/CSS/JS so that someone can properly debug it.

Comment: I would suggest nesting the submenu within the actual menu, then styling appropriately.  

Example:  

<ul>
  <li><span class="text">Menu 1</span>
    <ul>
      <li><span class="text">Submenu 1</span></li>
      <li><span class="text">Submenu 2</span></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><span class="text">Menu 2</span></li>
</ul>

Answer (score 0):

As @Justice said, it's easier to do this if your submenus are nested.  If you're going to keep the ULs separate, however, take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8447294/1226133) for some help.