# Keep submenu open on hover jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, navigation, hover

I have a dropdown menu I would like to remain open on hover. I was previously using .click() and it would stay open, but when i changed my code to .hover() it disappears as soon as i move my mouse off the top link. 
here is my code:

```
<nav>
            <div class="nav-mobile">
                <a id="nav-toggle" href="#"><span></span></a>
            </div>
            <ul class="nav-list">
                <li><a href="#">Solutions</a>
                    <ul class="nav-dropdown">
                        <li><a href="#">Click & Collect</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Endless Aisle</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Ship from Store</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Partner Dropship</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">In-Store Returns</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Fulfillment Optimization</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">The Way We Work</a>
                    <ul class="nav-dropdown">
                        <li><a href="#">Software as a Service</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Delivering Best Practice</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Reusable Integrations</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Partner Collaboration</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Sharing Success</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Living Our Values</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#"><img class="flag" src="assets/english.png" alt="">English</a>
                    <ul class="nav-dropdown">
                        <li><a href="#"><img class="flag" src="assets/cantonese.png" alt="">Cantonese</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><img class="flag" src="assets/japanese.png" alt="">Japanese</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><img class="flag" src="assets/korean.png" alt="">Korean</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><img class="flag" src="assets/mandarin.png" alt="">Mandarin</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
```

and here is my jquery: 
(

```
function($) {
    $(function() {
        $('nav ul li > a').not($('.only-child')).mouseenter(function(e){
            $(this).siblings('.nav-dropdown').slideToggle();
            $('.nav-dropdown').not($(this).siblings()).hide();
            e.stopPropagation();
        });
        $('nav ul li > a').not($('.only-child')).mouseleave(function(e) {
            $(this).siblings('.nav-dropdown').slideToggle();
            e.stopPropagation();
        })
        $('html').click(function(){
            $('.nav-dropdown').hide();
        });

        $('#nav-toggle').click(function() {
            $('nav ul').slideToggle();
        });

        $('#nav-toggle').on('click', function() {
            this.classList.toggle('active');
        });

    });
})(jQuery);
```

How can I make it work on hover?

Comment: then you have to comment mouseleave code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You made some mistakes with hover selector, you have to use `parent > child` selector. And remove mouseout effect, I made some changes to your code to be more readable, check this:

```js
$(".nav-dropdown").hide()
$('nav > ul > li > a:not(.only-child)').mouseenter(function(e){
    $('.nav-dropdown').hide();
    $(this).next('.nav-dropdown').slideToggle();
    e.stopPropagation();
});
/*$('nav ul li > a:not(.only-child)').mouseleave(function(e) {
    $(this).siblings('.nav-dropdown').slideToggle();
    e.stopPropagation();
})*/
$('html:not(.nav-dropdown)').click(function(){
    $('.nav-dropdown').hide();
});

$('#nav-toggle').click(function() {
    $('nav ul').slideToggle();
});

$('#nav-toggle').on('click', function() {
    this.classList.toggle('active');
});
```

```css
.nav-list > li{
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<nav>
            <div class="nav-mobile">
                <a id="nav-toggle" href="#">Slide List under me<span></span></a>
            </div>
            <ul class="nav-list">
                <li>
                    <a id="test1" href="#">Solutions</a>
                    <ul class="nav-dropdown">
                        <li><a href="#">Click & Collect</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Endless Aisle</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Ship from Store</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Partner Dropship</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">In-Store Returns</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Fulfillment Optimization</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">The Way We Work</a>
                    <ul class="nav-dropdown">
                        <li><a href="#">Software as a Service</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Delivering Best Practice</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Reusable Integrations</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Partner Collaboration</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Sharing Success</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Living Our Values</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#"><img class="flag" src="assets/english.png" alt="">English</a>
                    <ul class="nav-dropdown">
                        <li><a href="#"><img class="flag" src="assets/cantonese.png" alt="">Cantonese</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><img class="flag" src="assets/japanese.png" alt="">Japanese</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><img class="flag" src="assets/korean.png" alt="">Korean</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><img class="flag" src="assets/mandarin.png" alt="">Mandarin</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
```

Comment: this is great, thank you so much. much more clear than i was looking at it. were would i add in the mouse leave function? thanks for your help, i'm a new beginner at javascript/jquery and sometimes get in over my head

Comment: Glad to help. You can remove mouseout function if you dont need to do something when mouse is out, if not leave it and add the code you need to work.

Answer (score 0):

Check this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/8447294/7643918 , Nutail explained very nicely, you need to write code for mouse enter and mouse leave event.